# Flask function got multiple values for argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have this Python code:

```
@reports_api.route('/reports/xlsx/organisations/<int:organisation_id>/', methods=['GET'])
@reconnect_to_db
@check_permissions(request, employee_constraints={}, client_user_constraints={}, in_args=True)
def get_organisation_containers_report_xlsx(organisation_id, employee_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        recipient = request.args.get('recipient')
        report_str_io = ExcelReportsManager.get_organisation_containers_report(organisation_id, employee_id, recipient == 'up')
    return flask.jsonify(**report_str_io), 200
```

When i use route to this api, i've get error

```
TypeError: get_organisation_containers_report_xlsx() got multiple values for argument 'organisation_id'
```

There is the path, that leads to api:

```
http://localhost:5000/reports/xlsx/organisations/1/?employee_id=2
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error was in function args. Need to use `request.args.get('employee_id')`.

And code will be like this:

```py
@reports_api.route('/reports/xlsx/organisations/<int:organisation_id>/', methods=['GET'])
@reconnect_to_db
@check_permissions(request, employee_constraints={}, client_user_constraints={}, in_args=True)
def get_organisation_containers_report_xlsx(organisation_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        recipient = request.args.get('recipient')
        report_str_io = ExcelReportsManager.get_organisation_containers_report(organisation_id, request.args.get('employee_id'), recipient == 'up')
    return flask.jsonify(**report_str_io), 200
```

It works when we sending args in path to api like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/reports/xlsx/organisations/1/?employee_id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that the first argument is `path` in flask `route` methods , add `path` to the function signature as the first argument and check if it fixed that.

Comment: In flask path uses just for declaration route for api. It's not an a function argument, and can't be it, if you will not declare it yourself.